# Flutter Huawei Analytics iOS Bug

Tags: flutter, analytics, huawei-mobile-services

while it works normally on Huawei device, my app doesn't work on iOS device. It crashes after opening.

huawei_analytics: ^6.2.0+302

[image]

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.